# Requesting JSON data and inserting into fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity, android-xml

I have 3 tabs in my app, each having its own `Fragment`. I need to populate each tab's `Fragment` with data that needs to be retrieved from my website's REST API.

To my understanding, the `onCreate`/`onCreateView` method in the `Fragment` class is where I should request the JSON data (how do I request it?).

Then I would loop through the data and insert it into separate lists or cards (how do I do this?).

Sorry for the beginner questions, but I'm not sure where to begin.

Comment: Use `AsyncTask` to request `JSON` data and using its `onPostExecute` method to populate in the list or cards. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: Some code would be better to understand your question. However, JSON could be used in onCreate.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this

1) **through native android**

```
  private void makeGetRequest() {
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://www.example.com"); 
                            // replace with your url

    HttpResponse response;
    try {
        response = client.execute(request);

        Log.d("Response of GET request", response.toString());
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

2) use **third party libraries**.Please refer this url https://github.com/square/retrofit

*Example*
https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/samples/src/main/java/com/example/retrofit/SimpleService.java

This library will do all the things like GET,POST,Sync,Async and Error Handling.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use AsyncTask When youre requesting anything from server, Asynctask runs in backgrouns so your UI thread will no be blocked by it.

Otherwise you can try using Volly library dosen't need an AsyncTask to work. It will work in background thread anyway '

It also provides you with sucess failure handlers(if youre into ajax and all it'll easier for you)

take a look at [Volly Library](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)